# How to use JSON_TEXTCONTAINS oracle function with hibernate 5 in Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

The issue is that whatever I try in hibernate, it seems impossible to use this particular "unary" function from oracle text.

I know how to use JSON_VALUE function in hibernate, by doing

```java
Expression<String> expression = 
                        builder.function("JSON_VALUE", 
                                String.class, 
                                new HibernateInlineExpressionHelper(builder, "my_json_col"), 
                                new HibernateInlineExpressionHelper(builder, "'$.my_json_att'")
                        );
```

and then comparing the value using basic operator in hibernate like

```java
Predicate predicate = builder.like(expression, value + "%");
```

But then when it is about JSON_TEXTCONTAINS function, nothing works. I've tried creating this expression :

```java
Expression<Boolean> expression = 
                            builder.function("JSON_TEXTCONTAINS", 
                                    Boolean.class, 
                                    new HibernateInlineExpressionHelper(builder, "my_json_col"), 
                                    new HibernateInlineExpressionHelper(builder, "'$.my_json_att'"), 
                                    new HibernateInlineExpressionHelper(builder, "'my_json_val'"));
```

And then calling an equal true :

```java
Predicate predicate = builder.isTrue(expression);
```

But this is not supported by sql, error message is `"ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"`.

Or even :

```java
Predicate predicate = new BooleanExpressionPredicate((CriteriaBuilderImpl) builder, expression);
```

But this is not supported by hibernate at least for JSON_TEXTCONTAINS function, error message is

```java
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: function (JSON_TEXTCONTAINS) near line 1, column 301 [select rootAlias from MyEntity as rootAlias left join rootAlias.entityA as generatedAlias0 left join generatedAlias0.entityB as generatedAlias1 inner join rootAlias.contentType as generatedAlias2 where ( 1=1 ) and ( ( generatedAlias2.ref=:param0 ) and ( ( function('JSON_TEXTCONTAINS', my_json_col, '$.my_json_att1', 'my_json_val1') ) and ( function('JSON_TEXTCONTAINS', my_json_col, '$.my_json_att2', 'my_json_val2') ) and ( function('JSON_TEXTCONTAINS', my_json_col, '$.my_json_att3', 'my_json_val3') ) ) ) order by rootAlias.creationDate desc, rootAlias.id desc]
```

Those predicate I try to build are after concatenate like this :

```java
CriteriaQuery<MyEntity> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(MyEntity.class);
criteriaQuery.select(root)
                .where(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[]{}))
                .orderBy(orderList);
```

I have a lot of other predicates, with dynamic parameters, so building a native sql is not a possibility.

Do someone have an idea on how to use JSON_TEXTCONTAINS ?

The class HibernateInlineExpressionHelper comes from [this blog](http://www.istvandevai.com/2018/02/using-oracle-json-functions-via-jpa-and.html).

Comment: JSON_VALUE is a fonction that could be used in the SELECT and the WHERE part of the query, JSON_TEXTCONTAINS is like JSON_EXISTS: only in the WHERE clause, that may explain the different behavior.

Comment: Both of them are used in the where clause, does that mean JSON_TEXTCONTAINS cannot be used in a where clause from hibernate ?

Comment: I just pointed out a difference from ORACLE point of view, you should enable the tracing of queries to see what Hibernate generates.

Comment: I already done the tracing and each query seems ok, just it doesn't run. For SQL you cannot just do JSON_TEXTCONTAINS() = 1, and for hibernate as I said it doesn't support a function without an operator in the where clause. I've edited my question to add this precision.

Comment: And if you wrap JSON_TEXTCONTAINS in a function returning a number?

Comment: Good idea but not working, it seems JSON_TEXTCONTAINS does not return anything and is inherent to be used in a where clause. Kind of like a `attribute like '%1'`

Comment: try this:
create or replace function is_jsontextcontains(p_json IN VARCHAR2, p_target IN VARCHAR2)
return number
is
    v_result NUMBER;
begin
 with data(s) as ( select p_json from dual )
 select count(*) into v_result from data where  JSON_TEXTCONTAINS(s, '$', p_target);
 return v_result;
end;

Comment: Thank for you anwser, it seems it could work with this idea. I'm not an expert of oracle, but I can't get your function to work. I get `"first argument of JSON_TEXTCONTAINS needs to be a column`. It seems that putting `s` as column doesn't work. Still, I don't understand where the attribute of the json I want to fetch goes into your function. It should have a third parameter `p_att` and use it like `JSON_TEXTCONTAINS(s, '$.p_att', p_target)` no ?

Comment: It's why I put the WITH clause to wrap the parameter in a query from DUAL so it's a column when used in JSON_TEXTCONTAINS.

Comment: Yeah I understand but I still get : `ORA-40468: First input parameter to JSON_TEXTCONTAINS() must be a column.` Could you show me how do you want me to use your function ? Because maybe I don't get what you want me to achieve with this function.

Comment: by having a FUNCTION returning a NUMBER you should be able to register it in Hibernate:
create or replace function is_jsontextcontains(p_json IN VARCHAR2, p_target IN VARCHAR2)
return number
is
    v_result NUMBER;
begin
 with data(s) as ( select p_json from dual )
 select count(*) into v_result from data where  JSON_TEXTCONTAINS(s, '$', p_target);
 return v_result;
end;

The only limitation of JSON_TEXTCONTAINS you can't go around is that the path parameter MUST be a literal.
And this compiles fine here: Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production.